# Problem with Chrome/Chromium rendering bootstrap template (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, chromium

I'm having an issue with Chrome and Chromium not rendering a particular Twitter Bootstrap template properly. I'm using the [jumbotron template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/), and the log in form fields at the top don't seem to be getting the appropriate auto widths and are getting squished to the point where they are unusable. I have several machines running 14.04 and it only happens on one of them. I've tried purging and reinstalling Chrome and Chromium, but the issue persists. I'm hoping there is a way to fix this without reinstalling the whole OS. Below are the screenshots of the template in Chrome and Firefox for comparison.

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.btn-lg {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: perhaps you can help the OP out here - what does this do?  What do they need to do to add this setting.

Comment: This is just an almost command, but to me it doesn't look like one... We need to know how to use this. Remember Ubuntu is **Linux**.